# In a Spark cluster, is there one driver process per machine or one driver process per cluster?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am reading **Spark: The Definitive Guide** and am learning a great deal.

However, one thing I am confused about while reading is how many driver processes there are per Spark job. When the text first introduces driver and executor processes, it implies that there is a driver per machine, but in the discussion about broadcast variables, it sounds as though there is one driver per cluster.

This is because the text talks about the driver process sending the broadcast variable to every node in the cluster so that it can be cached there. That makes it sound as though there is only one driver process in the whole cluster that is responsible for this.

Which one is it: one driver process per cluster, or one per machine? Or can it be both? I think I am missing something here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Spark architecture, there will be only one driver for your spark application.

The spark driver, as part of the spark application is responsible for instantiating a spark session. The spark driver has multiple responsibilities

1. It communicates with the cluster manager (CM).
2. Requests resources from the CM for spark's executor JVMs.
3. Transforms all spark operations into DAG computations, schedules them and distributes their execution as tasks across all spark executors.

It's interaction with the CM is merely to get Spark executor resources.

So, the workflow of running spark applications on a cluster can be seen as:

- The user submits an application using spark-submit.
- spark-submit launches the driver program and invokes the main method specified by the user.
- The driver program contacts the cluster manager to ask for resources to start executor.
- The cluster manager launches executors on behalf of the driver program.
- The driver process runs through the user application. Based on the RDD or dataset operations in the program, the driver sends work to executors in the form of tasks.
- The tasks are run on executor process to compute and save result.